# UI bug android - screen not matched on top edge

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I'm working on this app and I have implemented a photo slider through ViewPager. There is an imported circle page slider indicator, a project on github. It looks like this: (Sorry for the blured text, I'm not able to share the content until release. The app will be free)

[image: Image slider]

My problem is that thin blue line on the top of the screen. Blue color comes from the background and it is set in the root layout of the activity. No matter what I do to the any of the layouts (changing margins or padding to negative values) this line remains there.

[image: Image slider]

So I figured that it has to do with the chosen theme for the screen. Theme is set to a custom theme which has `Theme.NoTitleBar` as it's parent. The code is below:

This is the style file. Taken from http://viewpagerindicator.com/ by Jake Wharton.

```
<style name="Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <!--<item name="vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.IconPageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>-->
    <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.CirclePageIndicator</item>
</style>
```

This is my activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/accountRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradientbg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        />

    <io.colomb.android.colombio.customviews.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/slideIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewPagerSlider"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSoftboardLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/logosoftboard"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/InputFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.001"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
    >
 </LinearLayout>
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK solved. The thing that was bothering the adapter was the line `gravity="bottom"`in the root element. Also the pictures needed to be cropped more